I have found the following equation in Titchmarsch "The theory of the Riemann zeta function" but I can't prove it
I was reading Titchmarsch "The theory of the Riemann zeta function" when i stumbled upon the following equation:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-n^2 \pi x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-n^2 \pi /x}$$
for x>0.
The book sells it as a known fact but frankly I would like to know why it is the case, a paper intitled "SUITE DES NOTICES
SUR LES FONCTIONS ELLIPTIQUES"
by Carl Jacobi credits the proof to Poisson, in issue 19 of the "Journal de l'Ecole polytechnique" but I can't find the issue anywhere online.
Does someone know how to prove this or where I can find a proof?

Rather than directly connected to the zeta function, it indeed is the so called theta transformation formula where $\theta(t):=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-n^2\pi t}$. The transformation formula states $\theta(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\theta(\frac{1}{t})$, which is exactly your equation. It can be shown using Poisson's summation formula (for Fourier series), for instance view https://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/fourier-analysis/theta-zeta.pdf.

Thank you, I have found it really helpful
